# Finding/figuring out pin configuration on undocumented components

Tags: components, datasheet, display, component-selection

I recently purchased an assorted set of LCD/LED displays, and inside there were a set of components which I cannot find a datasheet for upon googling the component number.

For instance in the component below:

[image]

I have googled what appears to be the serial number: HNM-05SS62T, but I cannot find a datasheet for this component. Also, googling Samsung SSED doesn't appear to yield any better results.

How do you go about identifying how to use a component like this in this case?

Comment: Forget about them and buy parts with data.

Comment: That looks like a VFD (Vacuum Fluorescent Display). Apart from the pinouts, the drive and supply voltages for these are quite high and a bit unusual nowadays.

Comment: Indeed, that looks like a VFD which will be tricky to figure out. For an LED with no interface circuitry you could probe with a current limited supply, while for a bare LCD with no driver you could probe with a low voltage (isolated) AC source - for example, a 3.3v logic level oscillator at a few KHz coupled through a capacitor.  Having a mental picture of the likely internal topology will help you understand its exact form and what pins play what role based on how it responds to your probing.

Answer (score 1):

A bit older post and a late reply, but I believe this answer may be useful for somebody. Just found a link which can explain the pins for this VFD

http://www.picaxeforum.co.uk/entry.php?142-LCD-LED-OLED-assorted-displays-lucky-bags-at-Maplin-2-(N01CG)-Kemo-Electronic-S043